# Are there bytes that are not used in the UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: unicode, binary

As I understand it, UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, and therefore includes the control characters which are not used to represent printable characters.

My question is: *Are there any bytes (of the 256 different) that are not used by the UTF-8 encoding?*

I wondered if you could *convert/encode* UTF-8 text to binary.

***Here my though process:***

I have no idea how the UTF-8 text encoding works and how it can use so many characters (only that it uses multiple bytes for characters not in ASCII (Latin-1??)) but I know that ASCII text is valid in UTF-8 so the [control characters (bytes 0-30)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout) are not used differently by the UTF-8 encoding but they are at the same time not used for displaying characters, right??

So of the 256 different bytes, only ~230 are used. For a 1000 (binary) long Unicode text there are only 1000^230 different texts? Right?

If that is true, you could *convert* it to a binary data which is smaller than 1000 bytes.

**Wolfram alpha**: [1000 bytes of unicode (assumption unicode only uses 230 of the 256 different bytes) --> 496 bytes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pow%28pow%281000%2C230%29%2C1%2F256%29)

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I have no idea how those three paragraphs are related.

Comment: @yamm Unicode does not deal with bytes *at all*. You may be confusing it with a character encoding such as UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: @Biffen yes im a bit confused by this. you are right ;-) i mean the utf encodings

Comment: ‘*UTF-8 text to binary*’ What?! UTF-8 *is* binary. What is it that you want to achieve, really?

Comment: @Biffen if there would be bytes not used by the utf-8 encoding you could convert utf-8 text to a smaller binary code.

Comment: So what you're actually asking is if it's possible to compress Unicode text.

Comment: Although there's a flaw in the train of logic here somewhere, it's hard to pinpoint exactly where; you're possibly confusing terminology (bit/byte) and it's possible you don't quite understand how binary/bits/bytes work.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) look at the UTF-8 encoding and you'll know if there are any unused values

Comment: i updated my post ;-) hopefully you understand my question a bit better now.

Comment: *"for a 1000(binary) long unicode text there are only 1000^230 different texts? right"* Wrong. You're mixing up bits and bytes as I suspected. One byte is 8 bits, and it doesn't matter if you have 256 different characters or 230; they both need 8 bits (one byte). Only if you can halve the characters needed to 128 or under you can use 7 bits (seven eights of a byte) to represent them.

Comment: @Juhana wouw now im really confued ;-) either i you destroyed my worldview of how bytes and bits work or you did not understand me. if utf-8 encoded text uses 230 of the 256 different bytes i can say that there are 1000^230 possible strings that are 1000 bytes long. while there are 1000^256 different *strings* that use all bytes. **example:** base 64 encoding uses only 64 of the 256 available bytes --> therefore its a lot larger that the original bynary data.

Comment: Yeah, you should get the bit/byte distinction cleared up. Base64 uses **64 characters** that represent **6 bits** (2^6 = 64). It works as compression because 6 bits is less than **8 bits** (2^8 = 256). Also, 1000^230 is the total number of different 1000-character long permutations you can make with 230 characters, but that has nothing to do with how many bytes 1000 characters takes.

Comment: As an example. consider a digital number panel that has 3 digits. You can show numbers 0-999 in this panel. If you wanted to show numbers 0-800, you would *still* need 3 digits in that number panel, even though you have 199 fewer numbers in the total range. If you have 100 numbers (0-99) then you can use only 2 digits. It's the same with binary numbers: there's no difference between 230 and 256 characters because you still need 8 bits to store both ranges.

Comment: @Juhana you actually dont seem to understand me.... all im saying is that 1000^230 in utf-8 has approximatly the same amout of different permutations as 496^256 --> therefore you could encode a 1000 unicode string to 496 of binary...

Answer (score 5):

0xF8-0xFF are not valid anywhere in UTF-8, and some other bytes are not valid at certain positions.

The lead byte of a character indicates the number of bytes used to encode the character, and each continuation byte has `10` as its two high order bits. This is so that you can pick any byte within the text and find the start of the character containing it. If you don't mind losing this ability, you could certainly come up with more efficient encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to devise encodings which are more space-efficient than UTF-8, but you have to weigh the advantages against the disadvantages.

For example, if your primary target is (say) ISO-8859-1, you could map the character codes 0xA0-0xFF to themselves, and only use 0x80-0x9F to select an extension map somewhat vaguely like UTF-8 uses (nearly) all of 0x80-0xFF to encode sequences which can represent all of Unicode > 0x80.  You would gain a significant advantage when the majority of your text does not use characters in the ranges 0x80-0x9F or 0x0100-0x1EFFFFFFFF, but correspondingly lose when this is not the case.

Or you could require the user to keep a state variable which tells you which range of characters is currently selected, and have each byte in the stream act as an index into that range.  This has significant disadvantages, but used to be how these things were done way back when (witness e.g. ISO-2022).

The original UTF-8 draft before Ken Thompson and Rob Pike famously intervened was probably also somewhat more space-efficient than the final specification, but the changes they introduced had some very attractive properties, trading (I assume) some space efficiency for lack of contextual ambiguity.

I would urge you to read the [Wikipedia article about UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) to understand the design desiderata -- the spec is possible to grasp in just a few minutes, although you might want to reserve an hour or more to follow footnotes etc.  (The Thompson anecdote is currently footnote #7.)

All in all, unless you are working on space travel or some similarly effeciency-intensive application, losing UTF-8 compatibility is probably not worth the time you have already spent, and you should stop now.

Answer (score 2):

You have to distinguish *Characters*, *Unicode* and *UTF-8 encoding*:

In encodings like ASCII, LATIN-1, etc. there is a one-to-one relation of one *character* to one number between 0 and 255 so a character can be encoded by exactly one byte (e.g. "A"->65). For decoding such a text you need to know which encoding was used (does 65 really mean "A"?).

To overcome this situation *Unicode* assigns every *Character* (including all  kinds of special things like control characters, diacritic marks, etc.) a unique number in the range from 0 to 0x10FFFF (so-called *Unicode codepoint*). As this range does not fit into one byte the question is how to encode. There are several ways to do this, e.g. simplest way would always use 4 bytes for each character. As this consumes a lot of space a more efficient encoding is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8): Here every *Unicode codepoint* (= *Character*) is encoded in one, two, three or four bytes (for this encoding not all byte values from 0 to 255 are used but this is only a technical detail).

Comment: @Brian allready mentioned that there are bytes that cannot occur in unicode ([the red ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout)). do you know about the control characters 0-31?

Comment: @yamm, the control characters are still valid unicode characters and some are still frequently used (tab, new-line, etc)

Comment: @yamm: of course there are many other "encodings" possible which need less space (e.g. just zip the UTF-8 encoded file)

Answer (score 0):

I found this 8+ years on and noticed no-one really answered it correctly:

(1) "Are there any bytes (of the 256 different) that are not used by the UTF-8 encoding?"

Answer: Yes, as you mentioned bytes 0-31 are not unique to UTF-8, but represent the same as in standard ASCII.
(In reality only bytes 0, 9, 10 and 13 are really in practicality used in both ASCII and UTF-8).

However, byte 127 is also practically never used in ASCII and UTF-8 (i.e. represents nothing), and bytes 128-255 are "extended ASCII" in ASCII, but totally different for UTF-8...

In UTF-8, bytes 128-255 are used to create unicode characters. e.g. Unicode sequence 226,157,164 is used for ❤, so the sequence I❤U is sequence 73,226,157,164,85.

(2) "So of the 256 different bytes, only ~230 are used. For a 1000 (binary) long Unicode text there are only 1000^230 different texts? Right?"

No, that is false because UTF-8 uses only bytes 128 to 255 for its unicode characters. Hence only 128 characters are used in creating its unicode character set. The only real downside is

Its a genius idea, really. You can mix ASCII with UTF-8 easily and OVERALL it takes much less space if your using just a few unicode chars.

The only downside is you can't efficiently index each character as an array of bytes, instead you have to read each character from the beginning until you get the index number you want!