# Are there any bytes that UTF-8 dosen't recognise?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I use the following code to write a String to a stream in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) format. I prefix my String's bytes with a signed short, then I write them out. There is an exception: I can't prefix with 0x0010 because it is a keyword in the final format. But I have to make sure that the reader ends up with the exact same string as my `str` parameter even if it's length is 0x0010.

```
public static void writeString(DataOutputStream out,String str) throws IOException{
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(CHARSET_UTF_8);
    if(bytes.length > Short.MAX_VALUE){
        throw new IOException();
    }
    short len = (short)bytes.length;
    if(bytes.length == 0x0010){
        len++;
    }
    out.writeShort(len);
    out.write(bytes);
    if(bytes.length == 0x0010){
        out.write(DEAD_BYTE);
    }
}
public static final Charset CHARSET_UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
```

Are there any bytes (of the 256) that UTF-8 dosen't recognise at the end of the string?

Also, the following question did not help me. I ended up with a `?` character at the end.
[30025693](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025693/are-there-bytes-that-are-not-used-in-the-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: Yes, 0xFF is one of the byte that can’t be anywhere in UTF-8. And anything ≥ 0xC0 can’t be last.

Comment: `0xff` gives `?` It dosen't work.

Comment: No idea what you mean. Is your question about what value you should use for DEAD_BYTE? (I don’t know java, no idea whether this is a language-defined value or something you defined yourself.) If so, I think you’d be fine with 0x00. Anyway, the way you handle that special value 0x10 looks so wrong to me…

Comment: This requirement about avoiding `0x0010` seems really strange. What happens if `\x00\x10` appears somewhere inside encoded string?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you're not using `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, anything you put into your UTF-8 string, will be decoded back as some character. If it's not a valid UTF-8 sequence, replacement character (`�`) will be used - and will still appear in your output.

You can just strip `�` from output string but it could also come from input string. Instead you should strip the extra byte from encoded UTF-8 bytes:

```
static String readString(final DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
    int len = in.readUnsignedShort();
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
    in.read(bytes);
    if (bytes[len - 1] == -1) {
        len--;
    }
    return new String(bytes, 0, len, UTF_8);
}
```

Another option is to skip `0x0010` when encoding length and move all values above by 1:

```
static void writeString(final DataOutputStream out, final String str) throws IOException {
    final byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(UTF_8);
    short len = (short) bytes.length;
    if (bytes.length >= 0x0010) {
        len++;
    }
    out.writeShort(len);
    out.write(bytes);
}

static String readString(final DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
    int len = in.readUnsignedShort();
    if (len == 0x0010) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    } else if (len > 0x0010) {
        len--;
    }
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
    in.read(bytes);
    return new String(bytes, UTF_8);
}
```

Both those solutions are hacks and will probably cause trouble in the future. The correct solution would be to remove this artificial limitation:

1. If you control the final format, redesign it so any byte sequence is allowed.
2. Otherwise, if `0x0010` is disallowed only at first position, always put a constant value there followed by the actual length. (for example: `00 11 00 10 ...`)
3. Otherwise, if `0x0010` cannot appear at any position, escape it: `\x00\x10` is encoded as `\\n` and `\` is encoded as `\\`

Finally `0x0010` looks like UTF-16 encoded new line. If it is indeed so, you shouldn't be putting binary data inside text - it will cause more problems than that. In that case you should put your string directly inside that UTF-16 encoded text or use ASCII-safe encoding like base64.